# Order by alphanumeric characters

Tags: mysql

I've seen several questions regarding this subject, but I cant make much sense of what I'm looking at, so I beg you to forgive me for asking a question that's been asked several times already - I've only started learning all of this sql, php, etc stuff about two weeks ago because I needed to make a tool to help me with my work, so I'm still an absolute begginer :(

Anyway, I'm using mysql and I'm making a query with:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col1
```

On "col1" I have values which look like:

```
1/16
2/16
12/16
37/12
74/16
114/13
225/16
etc
```

The values on this column always follow as "X/YY", where "YY" is ALWAYS two digits, and "X" can range from a single digit to five or six digits.
Understandably, as the column is set as varchar in order to accept the "/", when I try to order the values I get something like:

```
1/16
114/13
12/16
2/16
225/16
37/12
74/16
```

instead of what I'd want:

```
37/12
114/13
1/16
2/16
12/16
74/16
225/16
```

Meaning: first ordering by the two digits on the right, and then the ones on the left of the "/".
I understand I could probably do this easily by storing "X" and "YY" on different columns, but I'd really appreciate if someone could show me how to do it as it is.

Best regards,
T. F.

Comment: Best you can do is using string functions to split that column values (and if necessary convert them to numbers) and order by the computed values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`cast`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), you can sort to get your desired output.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `37031650`
ORDER BY
    cast(
        substring_index(col1, '/', - 1) AS signed INTEGER
    ),
    cast(
        substring_index(col1, '/', 1) AS signed INTEGER
    ) ASC
```

#### Examples

- [See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bc0e8/1)

```
mysql> select * from `37031650`;
+--------+
| col1   |
+--------+
| 1/16   |
| 114/13 |
| 12/16  |
| 2/16   |
| 225/16 |
| 37/12  |
| 74/16  |
+--------+
7 rows in set

mysql> select * from `37031650` order by cast(substring_index(col1,'/', -1) as signed integer), cast(substring_index(col1,'/', 1) as signed integer) asc;
+--------+
| col1   |
+--------+
| 37/12  |
| 114/13 |
| 1/16   |
| 2/16   |
| 12/16  |
| 74/16  |
| 225/16 |
+--------+
7 rows in set
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That seems to work just fine!
Cheers!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help @Baya `:)`